# Laravel 6: Encrypt/Decrypt with another hash, other than default

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

Given situation: 2 Laravel (v6.*) services needs to communicate between themselves and crypt/decrypt info from each other.

The ideal way was to use the built-in encryption methods through [Crypt facade](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php), however, the hash (secret) is not parsed through parameters in `encryptString` or `decryptString` function. I would have used this to pass the key according to service targeted and encrypt data to be sent to that specific service, but this is not an option.

In this case, is there a workaround to use the framework trough providers/traits or something or  needs to be developed for this specific case?

Yours truly

Comment: The default hashing driver for your application is configured in the config/hashing.php configuration file. There are currently three supported drivers: Bcrypt and Argon2 (Argon2i and Argon2id variants).  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing

Comment: True, but I need to encrypt data with 2 different keys (cyphers) on different cases in the same app. Your driver/config file reference doesn't cover the case.

Comment: The constructor takes in some arguments: `public function __construct($key, $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC')` Just new it up at runtime.